# How asp.net application works?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am quite new to .NET development and I am just wondering how does it work?

My undermentioned points are:

1. While developing ASP.NET application, under the project we have files like:

   - pagename.aspx
   - pagename.aspx.cs
   - pagename.asp.desiger.cs
2. After adding certain functionality to `pagename.aspx` page, assuming I have the development required web application (this is not my concern, what is developed)
3. Now I'm going to deploy this application, I use web deployment MSI which creates the required files in the one folder called `folderdelopyed`.
4. This folder contains the files required to support this application but interesting does not contain `pagename.aspx.cs` and `pagename.aspx.designer.cs` files.

My question is if `folderdelopyed` does not contain `.cs` file, then how does it work to run the segment of code which I have written in this file called `PageName.aspx.cs`?

Comment: Please dont use caps-lock. That is shouting.

Comment: @Valamas:ok I understood. Next it wont happen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in your cs files gets compiled into a dll.

For Web Application projects this is one dll

For Web Site projects, this is a dll per page.

All of the code is now in the dll's in the bin folder of the website.

You can use a tool like ILSpy (http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to look inside the dll's and see your code.

In the old days, for classic ASP, the script used to be embedded in your page - a mix of code and HTML, and was interpreted at runtime.

I like the new way more :-)

Comment: ok if class file complied to dll file, let us say user generate the request to web application what's happened then

Comment: You are asking about the HTTP Pipeline and how IIS responds to user requests for pages. Read http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp for more information.

Comment: Thanks for link, let me check and i will get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET code is compiled into *Dynamic-link library* files, also known as DLL files.

The code you write in your code behind, which is the files with `.cs` extension, is compiled and put into whole new file, with `.dll` extension - and that file **is** copied to the server, to the  *BIN* folder of your site.

Depending on what project type you choose, it's possible to have several DLL files for the web application, changing in every build - see [dash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338382/447356) for more details.

On every `.aspx` page you have referece to what DLL file to use, as the very first line. For example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="pagename.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyNameSpace.pagename" %>
```

In this example, the *Inherits* part determines what DLL to use. How? By the namespace, which is also the name of the DLL file.

When the above `.aspx` is requested by a browser, the .NET engine will go to the BIN folder, look for `MyNameSpace.dll` and in there look for class called `pagename` that inherits from the base `Page` class - all the rest is typical life cycle of ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 0):

let me to say you something more Amazing.

you can hide your aspx file  too.and put their content in to dll as same as your cs file put in dll.

you can make k aspx that just contain an address to the ddl file and no html body :D

that was greate!!! not only you can hide your cs file, you can hide you aspx file too :D